# PHP Includes requiring $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] how to disable to only use file location?

Tags: php, cpanel, include-path

Is there a way to disable/negate the use of $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] when including my php files?  I would prefer

```
require '/somedirectory/somefile.php';
```

instead of

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/somedirectory/somefile.php';
```

Running Centos and cPanel.

Or is this something that will always be required when writing my php code?

Comment: If you're _sure_ that your code will run without it and you're happy to change the references when/if your path changes then you can totally remove the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` from your code.

Comment: That will depend on if you plan on packaging this for distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use:

```
require './somedirectory/somefile.php';
```

Comment: O I see, you put a . in front of it.  I missed that completely! Thanks , That fixed the issue!

Answer (score 2):

```
require './somedirectory/file.php
```

works from the base of the application without explicitly referring to the $_SERVER ... There is no disabling but there is defining that variable or different variables to aid in your routing. variables like base_url and site_url

The dot refers to the root of the application.

Comment: upvoted your answer as I can't have two accepted answers.  The dot worked perfectly thanks.  It's the little things you always miss.

Comment: really glad it worked, I forgot to mention set include paths but the simplest way is the dot notation

Answer (score 0):

It's not required that you use those. You don't have to use full paths. Apache and PHP will generally look in the same path as the calling file (omit the `/` or PHP will think you mean the root of the server drive)

```
require 'somedirectory/somefile.php';
```

Another option is to set the [include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) so PHP knows where to look implicitly

```
set_include_path('/full/path/to/files');
```

Comment: see comments above